# Reuse of multiple CDI @Named bean instances of the same class in a JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, backing-beans

I'd like to use multiple instances of the same CDI Named bean in a JSF2 page. (Imagine I have a backing bean to access a contentmanager category, but I want to show multiple categories in the same JSF page) I wonder how can I "override" the default name of @Named annotation so I can have those 3 o 4 instances in my page. (¿Remember the old JSP "useBean" tag to use a bean in a page... you could use multiple instances of the same class this way)
I've search about beans.xml but don't find it. Can I use old faces-context.xml "managed bean" entry? Don't know if that will apply to a CDI @Named bean or can only be use for old non CDI managed beans.

thanks for any info, 
Ignacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make your bean @Dependent (or remove existing scope annotation), and as long as you don't use the bean twice in the same EL expression, you'll get new underlying instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one bean instance in a given scope. So for example, in one request, you can't have two instances of a request-scoped bean. That's the point of the scopes.

So I guess you should not have your beans managed at all. Just put them as request attributes and access them via EL.

Comment: I haved "included" the multiple funtionality in the CDI managed bean to replicate different instances. I want to use CDI and @named annotation but hoped that old way of including multiple beans used in JSP pages could be replicated in a similar way. thanks for your answer.